# Setting rightBarButtonItem from Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, swift

**How do you set the right bar button from the navigation controller instead of the view controller?**

I've been reading about writing SOLID view controller which work only as controllers instead of adding everything to them.

The post suggested to move the navigation logic outside the view controller (which I agree with). Also, the view controller really shouldn't be setting up the navigation controller it's embedded into, so I'm trying to move the code which sets up the navigation bar to my custom UINavigationController class.

I was partly successful, I managed to update the color, but wasn't able to set a `rightBarButtonItem`.

Adding these lines to the a view controller will work, but I want to do it from the UINavigationController subclass.

```
let settingsImage = UIImage(named: "settingsButton")
self.rightBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: settingsImage, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "showSettings")
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.rightBarButton;
```

I've looked at the questions "Default navigation button" which suggest creating a parent view controller and subclassing all view controllers from that, but I really don't like the fact that the view controller is setting up the navigation controller. It should be the other way around.

Edit: I got as far as `self.navigationBar.items`. If I set that to nil, nothing will be shown. So I probably need to change that. Not yet sure how though.

Comment: You created a UINavigationController subclass for doing this? left and right BarButtons are properties of the controllers navigationItem, not the navigationController. Each viewController in the viewControllers stack has its own navigationItem. I am not sure what you want to do is possible, but I will look into it.

Comment: @pedros Take a look at my edit.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Very weird question.

Comment: I wrote it as a comment to Fogmeister's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The navigation controller doesn't own the navigation bars that are displayed and so doesn't own the buttons on them.

The navigation controller pushes view controllers to the screen and gives them a navigation bar. The navigation bar is then configured (title, bar buttons, etc...) by the view controller. With the exception of the back button which is given a default configuration of the title of the previous controller.

So anyway, this is not "setting up the navigation controller" this is configuring the navigation bar that belongs to the view controller.

Best place for this is the view controller itself.

If you'd like a default button across the entire app then you could create a "parent subclass" for all your view controllers. (But then you're limited to the type of controller you can use).

Or I have done this in the past by creating a category on `UIBarButtonItem` with a method like this...

```
+ (UIBarButtonItem *)myDefaultButtonWithTarget:(id)target action:(selector)action
```

It means that you have to call it in each view controller you want ...

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [UIBarButtonItem myDefaultButtonWithTarget:self action:@selector(doSomething)];
```

But it means that you only need one line of code to do it instead of having to configure it each time. Also, you can change the button everywhere by changing the category.

Documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uinavigationbar

Comment: I like the category one, since everything will be centralized by doing that. Though I find it a bit weird that the navigation items are owned by the view controller. Well I suppose, every view controller implements its own navigation button, but now all the navigation item related code is scattered.